# How can I set twoside, symmetric layout for bookdown::tufte_book2()

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, tufte, bookdown

I'm using the fantastic new `bookdown` package, right off of [Yihui's boilerplate](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo), using the `bookdown::tufte_book2()` output.

The result is lovely, but I'd like the pages to be symmetrical, so that the margins are always on the outside of a two-sided book.

I understand that the [original tufte latex package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex?lang=en) [offered this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237704/table-of-contents-not-symmetric-with-tuftes-symmetric-option) via simply setting:

```
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{tufte-book}
```

**Where do I plug this into my bookdown project?**

I've tried just adding it to the `preamble.tex`, but that didn't do anything.

---

Ps.: Please don't shout at me that this is LaTeX question; it's really not. It's an `rmarkdown` / `bookdown` question which happens to *output* LaTeX.

Pps.: Have I mentioned how marvellous and beautiful Yihui's bookdown package this?
The future of (academic) (~nerdy) publishing is with us!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set `classoption` in the YAML metadata of `index.Rmd`:

```
---
classoption: twoside,symmetric
---
```

For more LaTeX variables, see http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html

Comment: yikes, that was dumb of me. Thanks for being so generous @Yihui, I admire your work.